# cross-origin request blocked with extra header

Tags: php, jquery, sql, cross-platform

I am creating a apps with sql stuffs and i am using a online database, everything works fine if i input this `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

But the next few lines i need this header as well `header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');`

Once i insert that and run my html and to run this particular php file, i will get this error

error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.gamestopica.net/andrew/login.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

anyone know what i should do to fit those 2 header under the same php file without the cross-origin error?

my php file

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    include_once('db.php');
    session_start(); 

    header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $verify = 0;

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `userdetails` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'")
or die("fail");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $passwordDB = $row["Password"];
        if($password == $passwordDB)
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            $result2 = json_encode(
                array("type"=>"true", "username"=>$_SESSION['user'])
                ); 
                echo $result2;
        }
        else
        {
            $result2 = json_encode(
                array("type"=>"false")
                ); 
                echo $result2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result2 = json_encode(
                array("type"=>"nothing")
                ); 
                echo $result2;
    }
?>
```

Comment: you can use htaccess file to solve this issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `header()` is not valid syntax for that function. Try changing:

```
header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

to

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

and see if that fixes your issue.